# Area proportional 4 way Venn diagram

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, area

I am trying to create a 4 way area proportional Venn diagram:

[image]

Is it possible to calculate the dimensions of each rectangle, if I know the area of all 15 rectangles and set the length of one of the sides of one of the rectangles fixed? I would be happy to do it with ellipses or triangles instead if possible.

Comment: How would you calculate with 2 and 3 area's?

Comment: Two of your regions are not rectangles, but are L-shaped.  How would you relate those to the others?

Comment: @BrianTung I would just subtract the small rectangle from the large rectangle to get the are of the L-shaped polygon with 6 sides.